# Create spacing in the text that is written within the item

Tags: itemize, line-spacing

[image]I have the following code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf {XXX:} XXX XXXX XXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX X X X XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
```

How can I create line spacing (when it goes to the next line) and change the font size of the text? I do not want to create separation between the item.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "create line spacing". Please also clarify what types of font size changes you're considering.

Comment: Regarding the added image: Is this what you want to get? https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZAbk.png? One item with the regular spacing, another item with a larger linespacing? The text in both items is also larger that the surrounding text.

Comment: Yes. This is what I want.

Comment: @Odrisso: I have updated my answer accordingly. I have also edited the tags as this question is unrelated to overleaf or latex3 but appears to be more about line-spacing in an itemize environment.

Comment: Thanks. How do i control the spacing. like if I want to use spacing of 1.5 than double,

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are interested in the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text using the lipsum command. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{itemize}
\doublespacing \large
\item \textbf {XXX:} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item \textbf {XXX:} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

---

Update regarding the recently added image in the original question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text using the lipsum command. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{itemize}
\large
\item \textbf {XXX:} \lipsum[1][1-3]

\doublespacing
\item \textbf {XXX:} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to create spacing in the line when it goes to the next line. I can't create spacing on that.

Comment: Do you want a horizontal lindentation? Please add a sketch of the desired output to your question. Probably this helps to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Hi, The example you are showing, you have two items. and each Item has a line, that expands to 3 consecutive lines. I want to create spacing in these 3 lines. Also, wants to change the font of the items. Please let me know if it is clear now?

Comment: Unfortunately I still have a hard time understanding how exactly the spacing should look like. I still think, a sketch would help a lot here. Nevertheless, here is another guess: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxR40.png

Comment: I have added an image.

Comment: @Odrisso -- You say you have added an image.  Where is it?

Answer (score -1):

item separator can be set to positive or negative value

```
\begin{itemize}
      \setlength\itemsep{1em}%------------or{-1em}
      \item one
      \item two
      \item three
    \end{itemize}
```

Comment: I want to create separation in the text that is written within the item. Not creating separation between the item.